# move cursor in c++ using gotoXY and kbhit

Tags: c++, kbhit

I want to move the position of symbol "A" in the terminal via the following code in c++, but the terminal closes and seems it does not enter the for loop. I don't know where I am wrong. I will be grateful if you help me:

'w' should move it up
's' should move it down
'a' and 'd' to right and left

```
 #include <iostream>
 #include <conio.h>
 #include <string>
 #include <Windows.h>
 using namespace std;

 void goToXY(int x=0,int y=0)
 {
     HANDLE h=GetStdHandle(STD_OUTPUT_HANDLE);
     COORD c;
     c.X=x;
     c.Y=y;
     SetConsoleCursorPosition(h,c);
 }

 int main()
 {

     char symbol='A';
     int X=0, Y=0;

     goToXY(X,Y);
     cout<<symbol;

     for(;;)
     {
         if(kbhit())
         {
             char ch = getch();
             switch(ch)
             {
             case 'w':
                 goToXY(X,Y-1);
                 cout<<symbol;

             case 's':
                 goToXY(X,Y+1);
                 cout<<symbol;

             case 'a':
                 goToXY(X-1,Y);
                 cout<<symbol;

             case 'd':
                 goToXY(X+1,Y);
                 cout<<symbol;
             }
         }

         getch();
         return 0;
    }    
}
```

Answer (score 0):

1) You forgot to add `break;` after each `case`-body.

2) And you've put `return 0;` in the body of `for`-loop, so your program stops after first iteration.

Try this:

```
for(;;)
{
      if(kbhit())
      {
           char ch = getch();
           switch(ch)
           {
           case 'w':
               goToXY(X,Y-1);
               cout<<symbol;
               break;
           case 's':
               goToXY(X,Y+1);
               cout<<symbol;
               break;
           case 'a':
               goToXY(X-1,Y);
               cout<<symbol;
               break;
           case 'd':
               goToXY(X+1,Y);
               cout<<symbol;
               break;
          }
     }
}
getch();
return 0;
```

Answer (score -1):

You have not used the break; statement after each case in your switch statement. Hope this helps.

```
switch(ch)
               {
               case 'w':
                   goToXY(X,Y-1);
                   cout<<symbol;
                   break;
               case 's':
                   goToXY(X,Y+1);
                   cout<<symbol;
                   break;
               case 'a':
                   goToXY(X-1,Y);
                   cout<<symbol;
                   break;
               case 'd':
                   goToXY(X+1,Y);
                   cout<<symbol;
                   break;
               }
```

Comment: Thanks all for quick responses